# How to breakup a fastify plugin into multiple files that provides routes?

Tags: typescript, fastify

I'm working on a simple fastify typescript plugin that provides multiple routes.  It's pretty easy for these routes to get too long so I'd like to be able to break them up into separate files.

When I break them up into separate files, what's the best way to ensure I can forward the `fastify` object and access any decorated objects associated with `fastify`?

For example, I'd like a cleaner way to accomplish the same as this:

```js
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from "fastify";

const exampleHandler = async (request, reply, fastify) => {
  console.log(fastify.promptExecutor);
  return "Example1";
};

const example: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get("/example1", async (request, reply) => {
    return exampleHandler(request, reply, fastify);
  });

  fastify.get("/example2", async (request, reply) => {
    console.log(fastify.promptExecutor);
    return "example2";
  });
};

export default example;
```

In this example, `promptExecutor` is some object I decorated onto `fastify` with another plugin.

I tried doing something different like

```js
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from "fastify";

const exampleHandler = async (request, reply) => {
  console.log(this.promptExecutor);
  return "Example1";
};

const example: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get("/example1", exampleHandler.bind(fastify));

  fastify.get("/example2", async (request, reply) => {
    console.log(fastify.promptExecutor);
    return "example2";
  });
};

export default example;
```

But in that scenario `this` is possible undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to write `exampleHandler.bind(fastify)` when the `exampleHandler` is an anonymous function.

It would work if it is a named function:

```
async function exampleHandler (request, reply) {
  console.log(this.promptExecutor);
  return "Example1";
};
```

Anyway, [Fastify does it for you](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/):

> handler(request, reply): the function that will handle this request. The Fastify server will be bound to this when the handler is called. Note: using an arrow function will break the binding of this.

So you can create a file for each handler:

```js
// foo.ts
async function exampleHandler (request, reply) {
  console.log(this.promptExecutor);
  return "Example1";
};
export default { exampleHandler }
```

```
import { exampleHandler } from './foo'
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from "fastify";

const example: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get("/example1", exampleHandler);
};

export default example;
```

Comment: This is what I get for reading the docs a little too quickly.  I missed that section.  Thank you!